# Use MessagePack with unity in DLL

Tags: unity-game-engine, msgpack

Simple question,

I have made a dll that uses MessagePack (from nuget). Unfortunately it seems you cannot just drop the MessagePack dll directly into unity as it generates a bunch of errors. I was trying to find the best way to add message pack binaries to unity when I noticed that there is a `unitypackage` file that adds all the source code to the unity project. This, however is useless to me as my external library (my dll) contains a reference to MessagePack.

In the documentation, the author suggests using a shared project for the messages. If I use the attributes in the `MessagePack` namespace in my external library, then I need to have a reference to `MessagePack.dll`. Dropping the dll into my unity project generates all kinds of errors... Sort of a catch 22...

Any idea how I should go about this?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you when you don't even post those error messages?

Comment: What version of unity are you using?

Comment: @buffalo94 2018.1.2.f1

Comment: @TurboJ `unloading broken assembly.. this assembly can cause crashes in the runtime` is the main error. all of the others are side-effects of this one. In any case, there are too many to post here. 999+

Comment: Make sure the dll doesn't use incompatible API. You said there is a unitypackage why not using it and then compile it in a empty project that will produce a dll based on Unity .Net compatibility Level